# Can I Install Multiple Versions of the Same Package Using DNF?

Tags: fedora, package-management, dnf, pip

I have multiple versions of Python on my machine, and attempting to install Pip for each of them. I have already installed Pip 21.2.3 for Python 3.10 and am now trying to install Pip 20.3.X (specific version number isn't much of an issue) for Python 3.9. Can I use DNF to install Pip 20.3 after I have already installed a more recent release, and if so, how?

Fedora Linux 35, DNF version 4.14.0.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do a 'manual' setup.

First you need to download the exact package, with specifying which exact version you want, and what is a folder to keep the package:

```
$ dnf download --downloadonly --downloaddir=/downloadpath package-a.b.c
```

Then you can do a setup, into specific dir

```
$ dnf install --installroot=/installpath /downloadpath/package-a.b.c
```

All paths must be absolute.